# function not saving string on textfield to core data

Tags: swift, core-data, entity, fetch, swift5

My function below when called is not saving whatever is on the textfield to core data. When appearing in the debugg area what appears is "". THis code when used in the view did load function it does work but when I call it it does not work.

```
func timTebow(){

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Item", in: context)
    let newUser = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)


    newUser.setValue(playName.text, forKey: "atBATS")
    do {

        try context.save()

    } catch {

        print("Failed saving")
    }

    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Item")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    do {
        let result = try context.fetch(request)
        for data in result as! [NSManagedObject] {
            print(data.value(forKey: "atBATS") as? String)
        }

    } catch {

        print("Failed")
    }
}
```

Comment: So is `playName.text` empty when you look in debugger? If you write `print("PLAYNAME: \(playName.text)")` just before `newUser.setValue(..:)` execute and call the function from the place that doesn't work, what is the output in Console?  If it's empty, can you show the code in `viewDidLoad(...)` function? Can you also check if you set playName.text = "" or to some variable that might be empty in some case? Where do you set `playName.text` in the code base?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rb93byxmtp08923/CoreDataDemo-master.zip?dl=0 this is a link to my project. Focus on functions Tim and saver. Function saver is saving the image correctly func Tim is not saving the string that is where I need help.

Comment: Do you implement any `textFieldDelegate` methods? Alternatively, do you `resignFirstResponder` on the textField?

Comment: I used a function to respond first responder what textfielddelegate would I use?